# os.walk listing directory

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, file-system

I use this script to get a list of all my photos in a folder and its subfolders. However, the program seems to be really slow.

There are 50,000 .jpg pictures in this folder and subfolders. I can reduce the `for` loops but the program still runs more or less at the same speed.

I am open to using lambda as well but would like to use Python's basic functions at the best possible speed. Can anyone suggest an improvement?

```
import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch
import sys

root = "C:\\Users\\Agartha\\Desktop\\photos"
pattern = "*.jpg"

with open("./files\\list.txt", "w") as a:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
       for filename in files:
            if fnmatch(filename,pattern):
                a.write(str(os.path.join(filename)) + '\n')
```

Comment: Why do you `os.path.join` on a single argument? Did you meant to write `os.path.join(path, filename)`?

Comment: did you consider using regex for the pattern matching?

Comment: @A.Romeu `fnmatch` actually convert the pattern to a regex under the hood. See the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/fnmatch.py),

Answer (score 2):

Here you do 4 things at the same time. Your are

1. Walking over all the files of the directory
2. Comparing the filename to a pattern
3. Formatting the filename
4. Appending the filename to a file

To find out what is the slower step, you should decouple this

```
def find_files(root):
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for filename in files:
            yield filename

def filter_filename(files, pattern):
    for filename in files:
        if fnmatch(filename,pattern):
            yield filename

def format_filenames(files, root):
    for filename in files:
        yield str(os.path.join(filename)) + '\n'

def writelines(out_file, files):
    for filename in files:
        out_file.write(filename)
    # or:
    # out_file.writelines(files)

def main(root, pattern, filename_out):
    files = find_files(root)
    files_filtered = filter_filename(files, pattern)
    files_formatted = format_filenames(files, root)
    with open(filename_out, 'w') as out_file:
        writelines(out_file, files_formatted)
```

Then Afterwards, there are 4 things you can time individually to find out the largest culprit in time consumption and work on that one:

1. `files = list(find_files(root))`
2. `files_filtered = list(filter_filename(files, pattern))`
3. `files_formatted = list(format_filenames(files, root))`
4. `with open(filename_out, 'w') as out_file: writelines(out_file, files_formatted)`

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that your method relies heavily on your hard drive. The process needs to recursively look inside every sub-folder, which takes time, especially with 50000 files.

[Windows search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Search) is much faster because it indexes the files and doesn't scan the whole drive for each query.

If using Python3 is a possibility, the only thing I'd change in your code is to use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) and replace the loops with:

```
import glob
glob.glob("C:\\Users\\Agartha\\Desktop\\photos\\**\\*.jpg", recursive=True)
```

Comment: if he uses Python 3, I would use [`pathlib.Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) instead of `glob.glob`

Comment: @MaartenFabré: It really depends what OP wants to do with it. If it's just to write filenames into a file, glob.glob will be more than enough. For anything more complex, pathlib is great indeed.

Answer (score 2):

For starter, you could organize your code into functions and use the [`if __name__ == '__main__'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard.

You could also change the construct `for` loop + `if fnmatch.fnmatch` into [`for … in fnmatch.filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter).

This would yield something like:

```
import os
import fnmatch

def filter_files(path='~/Desktop', filter_pattern='*.jpg'):
    for root, _, filenames in os.walk(os.path.expanduser(path)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, filter_pattern):
            yield os.path.join(root, filename)


def write_to_file(iterable, filename='files/list.txt'):
    with open(filename, 'w') as output:
        for element in iterable:
            output.write(element)
            output.write('\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pictures = filter_files('~/Desktop/photos')
    write_to_file(pictures)
```

However, this code can be greatly improved if you switch to using Python 3.5+ as the recursive filtering is exactly implemented in [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/glob.html#glob.glob):

```
import glob


def write_to_file(iterable, filename='files/list.txt'):
    with open(filename, 'w') as output:
        for element in iterable:
            output.write(element)
            output.write('\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pattern = 'C:\\Users\\Agartha\\Desktop\\photos\\**\\*.jpg'
    pictures = glob.iglob(pattern, recursive=True)
    write_to_file(pictures)
```

You could still maintain the `filter_files` function for easier interface:

```
import glob
from os.path import expanduser, join as path_join


def filter_files(path='~/Desktop', filter_pattern='*.jpg'):
    pattern = path_join(expanduser(path), '**', filter_pattern)
    yield from glob.iglob(pattern, recursive=True)


def write_to_file(iterable, filename='files/list.txt'):
    with open(filename, 'w') as output:
        for element in iterable:
            output.write(element)
            output.write('\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pictures = filter_files('~/Desktop/photos')
    write_to_file(pictures)
```